# Using IP address to Communicate with android device

Tags: javascript, php, android, ajax

I have the IP address and the mac address of an android device connected to a separate network. And I want to communicate with it using `PHP` or `ajax`, the android device isn't pre-registered and it can change. Thus the first contact is established by the device to send the IP and MAC addresses.

I want to be able to send and receive data with the device without his interaction, for instance, I can wait for the android device to contact the server and place an action in PHP like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $PageAction = $_GET['action'];
} else {
    $PageAction = 'NoAction';
}
switch ($PageAction) {
    case "first_action":
           echo "android_action_todo";    
        break;
   
    default:
        echo "No option is selected!";
}
```

the android device can now send to the `URL` of the server with `/phpfile.php?action=first_action` and get the echoed string `android_action_todo`.

I want to reverse this interaction to be able to send data from the server to the device so that I don't have to wait for the android player to make the `first interaction`, to be able to get the data in real-time and not have to wait for the android device, it may take seconds, minutes or hours even.

Comment: Your question is way too vague and broad. If you want PHP to send data to an android device, that device needs to either make a request to your server which simply responds with the data, or you need to have some app that allows incoming traffic that your server can make requests to. Sockets might make sense. However, you need to add way more details of your setup, together with some proper explanation of what you've tried and exactly where you're stuck. There's a lot of _"I want..."_ but no _"I've tried..."_ here.

Comment: if let's say the android app can handle the incoming request from the server can I use `ajax ` using the IP address of the android device to send the request? example:`$.post("96.158.226.150/action=first",{data:data},function(result){});`

Comment: Why not try it? We're not here as rubber ducks, we're here to help out if you run intp some _specific_ issue that you can't solve yourself. You still need to do some extensive research and some real attempts first. Then you need to show us what you've tried, expected result and explain what actually happens.

Comment: I wanted to verify that using `ajax` can reach the device, as you know the IP that I am getting from the device is the IP of the network it is in, would it be broadcasted to all? or discarded? and for the most part, I need to make big changes to the way my code is running at the moment, and with little time on my hand, I though it doesn't hurt to ask if it is doable before shifting everything right?

Answer (score 0):

To enable your Android device to respond to an incoming request initiated by the server, you have a few options:

- Have the Android device to be running a webserver, and for it to be exposed on the firewall / NAT router of the network it is on. Challenge: complex, and requires the network to be configured correctly.
- Establish a websocket connection from the Android device to your server, and use this to initiate an operation from the server. Challenge: the device needs to be running the app / webpage.
- Use Android push notifications.